# Does optical isomerism fall under the category of stereoisomerism?

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry, halides, hydrocarbons, optical-properties

I have been asked to find the total number of dichlorination products (including stereoisomers) for the following reaction:
[image]

I have figured out nine possible structures out of which two are optically active.

Should I count the additional six isomers (three for each of the optically active structures - RR, RS, SS)?

I am confused about whether to count the optical isomers or not.

Please provide clarification on this.
[image]

Comment: There are no additional six isomers. You've already counted them all.

Comment: @IvanNeretin Won't there be three different R-S structures for each of the optically active structures (because of the two chiral carbons)?

Comment: Indeed there will, and you've already counted them all. Your "optically active" are RR and SS, and your "meso" is RS.

Comment: @IvanNeretin oh, I just realized. This is now clear to me! This was a rather silly confusion.

Comment: The answer to the literal title question is, by the way, YES.